# Artifactory Remote Repository

Tags: caching, artifactory, artifacts

I'm new to Artifactory. I'm trying to understand better how the remote repository cache mechanism works.

Right know I have 3 imported remote repositories at the system:

1. google-code-cache.
2. java.net-cache.
3. jcenter-cache.

At the first two (google and java), After I'm entering to the remote url and downloading an artifact it seems to be saved at the repository-cache.

At `jcenter` that doesn't work. even if I'm downloading a file the file doesn't goes to the cache.

Can anyone help me understand better the logic behind the cache mechanism - when does it save the artifacts at the cache and when it's don't?

Thanks, 
Nadav

Comment: Have you managed downloading file via the JCenter remote repo? which URL did you use when trying to download? did you see any errors in the artifactory.log?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with JCenter you don't need the other repositories. You'll be able to retrieve all the artifacts from `java.net` and `google-code` directly from `jcenter`.

Second, the easiest way to configure remote repositories is using the configuration import functionality. Just click on the Import button. The default server to import from will be repo.jfrog.org, which is a good choice, since it has a lot of remote repos to choose. Select 'jcenter' from the list of the proposed repositories and it will be added to your Artifactory and configured correctly.